# SPRING - Soap exception: Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction:

Tags: java, spring, soap

i'm using jaxb2-maven-plugin to create the schema class from a WSDL

The SOAP server support soap1.1 and soap 1.2

I configure my client in this way

```
@Configuration
public class SoapClientConfiguration {

    @Bean
    Jaxb2Marshaller simplyJaxb2Marshaller(){
        Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
jaxb2Marshaller.setPackagesToScan("com.project.schema");
        return jaxb2Marshaller;
    }

     @Bean
      public WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate() throws SOAPException {
         WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate();
            webServiceTemplate.setMarshaller(jaxb2Marshaller());
            webServiceTemplate.setUnmarshaller(jaxb2Marshaller());

            webServiceTemplate.setDefaultUri(URL);

            return webServiceTemplate;

     }
```

When i try to use the `webserviceTemplate` i get the exception... No error if i try to make the response with for instance SOAP-UI or similar... it looks like the exception is thrown because of the SOAP version but how can i choose which version to use?